# Using Arcgis geometry in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, arcgis-server

I am sending request to Arcgis Rest service and getting result as JSON object.

[image]

I want to zoom to this Ring array.

```
var extent = new OpenLayers.Bounds(extent.geometry.rings[0]);
```

I tried but did not work. I am new at OpenLayers.

Comment: If you do console.log(extent.geometry.rings[0]); what do you see in your debugger console?

Comment: I show in that picture

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to find anything built-in going through the docs, only [this ticket](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/ticket/3661) which does not appear to have ever been merged into OpenLayers.

You can use [the open-source Terraformer library by Esri](https://github.com/esri/Terraformer) to convert from Esri JSON to GeoJSON, then use the standard GeoJSON functions in OpenLayers to act on it from there.

Alternately, it appears you can glue the two together easily enough with pure OpenLayers/Esri JS API:

```
require(["esri/geometry/Polygon"],
        function(Polygon)
        {
            var poly = new Polygon(extent);
            var new_extent = poly.getExtent();
            var ol_extent = new OpenLayers.Bounds(new_extent.xmin, new_extent.ymin,
                                                  new_extent.xmax, new_extent.ymax);
            // Zoom to ol_extent   
        });
```